# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given? Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

I've found many question realated to my problem but couldn't found an answer yet. It's about my foreach loop in my blade.

I want to print all product-names in my blade but I couln't figure out how to do that.

thats how I'm getting the products:

--- current code:

```
// controller 

    $id_array = Input::get('id');
    $products= Products::whereIn('id', $id_array)->get();
    $product_name = [];
    foreach($products as $arr)
    {
        $product_name=  $arr->lists('name');
    }
```

returning $product_name gives me this as a output:

```
["football","cola","idontknow","freshunicorn","dummy-data"]
```

In my blade is just a simple:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product}}
@endforeach

Error: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are getting an object in an array in an array.

Like this:

```
array(
   array(
    object
  )
)
```

It happens because you use the get() function to retrieve you model. The get() function always "wants" to retrieve multiple models. Instead you will have to use the first() function.

Like this:

```
foreach($id_array as $arr)
{
    $want2editarray[] = Product::where('id', $arr)->first();
}
```

Hope it helps :)

**Edit after @Wellno comment**

That's probably because Product::where('id', $arr)->first(); returns null because it did not find anything.

I forgot to add a check after the retrieving of the product.

This can be done like this:

```
foreach($id_array as $arr)
{
    // First try to get model from database
    $product = Product::where('id', $arr)->first();

    // If $product insert into array
    if ($product) $want2editarray[] = $product;
}
```

Comment: the controller output is the same, thats good. If I want to print $product->name in my blade, I'm getting an trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Edited my answer to fix your problem @WellNo

Comment: I allready did that :) but this haven't solved my problem.. my blade still gives me a : trying to get property of non-object -- I will update my question with my current code :)

Comment: There is a typo in your code :). You are using $products in your if statement and filling your array with $products. Use $product without and 's'.

Comment: oh, sorry, that was a mistake by me.. in my controller it's just product, I don't know how the 's' got in there :D

Comment: I've updated my question with current, much shorter code -- but still the same error - htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use loop with IDs? You can find all products by IDs:

`$products = Product::whereIn('id', $id_array)->get();`

And then use `$products` in the blade template

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried it exactly like you told me but this just gives me an error too : htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I've updated my question with current, much shorter code -- but still the same error - htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Please, show `$product` variable. Before `{{ $product->name }}` write `<?php dd($product); ?>`

Comment: now I've updated it, I think there is everything we need :)

Comment: Try `{{ implode(',', $product->name) }}`

Comment: I allready tried that but this just gives me : implode(): Invalid arguments passed -- and why $product->name? I allready have all the names I want from the lists function. | `implode(',', $product_name);` is what I did

Answer (score 0):

try to use Model/Eloquent to fetch data.
View should only display the data and not fetching directly from DB or do heavy calculations.

Comment: my view doesn't fetch any data directly from my database. I'm getting what I want in my controller and sending all the data to my view.